# Couldn't find hbase jar on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, jar, hbase

I want to run a simple program on hbase by eclipse and following step on:

https://www.guru99.com/handling-tables-hbase.html

but when I **add external jar** on myself, hbase-version.jar and hadoop-version-core.jar isn't in my /hbase/lib
Are these two jars important?

Where can I get those two jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the hadoop core jar [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/1.2.1) and hbase jar [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase/0.90.2)

[or]

Please convert your project to maven.

In pom.xml add the below dependencies

Hadoop Core jar

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

HBase jar

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
    <version>0.92.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Yes, both jars are important. Hadoop core jar contains the core apis like TaskTracker, JobTracker, InputSplit etc.

HBase jar contains core apis like zookeeper, rest, thrift, mapreduce etc.